# Is image map required for different links on image?

Tags: html, css

I'd like the top left corner of an image to link to location1 and the rest of the image to link to location2.  What would be the best way to do that?

Is there a more modern way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding additional details (such as code) to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you are asking for as everything is there. The scenario is as simple as I described. But thanks for the down vote.  Would be nice to get a few more before I accept the answer.

Comment: More modern than what?

Comment: What the what are you whatting about?

Comment: What does your code look like now? How do we know you're not already doing it modern?

Comment: @4thSpace Given your time on SO, you should be familiar with [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions. Questions should contain some source code (a minimal example at the least). Your question presents a general problem that you haven't attempted. ypercube was asking for you to be more specific about what you're comparing to, as it seems there might be code you're not showing us. If you hover your mouse over the downvote button, you will see "This question does not show any research effort" in the tooltip. I will gladly reverse my vote once your question shows effort.

Comment: The down vote is fine.  Leave it.  It's the SO way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you won't use `<map>`, try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UfLry/embedded/result/), '[source](http://jsfiddle.net/UfLry/)'

### HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="http://google.com/">
        <img src="http://kaleidoscope.cultural-china.com/chinaWH/upload/Image/colors2.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a class="corner" href="http://apple.com/"></a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
a.corner{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: When I click in the jsfiddle result, nothing happens.

Comment: @4thSpace it works with me, the left top corner takes you to apple.com , but the lest of the image take you to google.com

Comment: Also works for me.  @4thSpace how close to the top left corner did you go?  Adding a `border: 2px solid white;` to the a.corner can help show the area that leads to apple.com.

Comment: ok, the apple link in the corner does work but not the google link for the main image.  Does that work for you guys?

Comment: @4thSpace google.com link is working for me with **Chrome** and **Internet Explorer**, and it should do for you, because there is no link simpler than <a href="http://google.com/"> <img src="imageURL"/> </a> (it works only if the image loaded because I didn't add height to the img)

Comment: I've tried in Safari and FF.  Neither work.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways.

1. Image map
2. Javascript click handler, examine (x,y) and make the correct decision
3. Overlay an element in the top left corner of the image, using position: absolute or position:relative, and handle clicks on that separately.  [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194311/96) shows this approach.
4. Break the image up into 4 images - the top left image would link to location 1, and the other 3 would link to location 2.

Can you give more details on your use case?